# Как реализовать подобное меню

Tags: html, css

Как реализовать подобное меню так, чтобы было сходства как на макете?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста описание того что вам нужно ещё и словами с описанием что именно у вас затруднения вызывает. По одной картинке сложно понять в чём у вас проблема и сложно что-то ответить

Answer (score 0):

Только надо еще паддинги шрифт и т.д

```
 <div class="menu">
      <a href="">HOME</a>
      <a href="">PHOTOAPP</a>
      <a href="">&#8251;</a>
      <a href="">DESIGN</a>
      <a href="">DOWNLOAD</a>
    </div>

.menu
{
  background: #000;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;

}
.menu a
{
   text-decoration:none;
  color:#fff;
  padding-left:25px;
}
```

Comment: а как добавить logo?

Comment: вместо <a href="">&#8251;</a> <img src="">